# Why does IdentityHashMap use 2/3 as the load factor instead of 0.75?

Tags: java, data-structures, hash, hashmap, thread-local

```java
public class IdentityHashMap<K,V>
    extends AbstractMap<K,V>
    implements Map<K,V>, java.io.Serializable, Cloneable
{
    /**
     * The initial capacity used by the no-args constructor.
     * MUST be a power of two.  The value 32 corresponds to the
     * (specified) expected maximum size of 21, given a load factor
     * of 2/3.
     */
    private static final int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 32;
    
    // omitted
}
```

From [jdk/IdentityHashMap.java at jdk8-b120 · openjdk/jdk · GitHub](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/jdk8-b120/jdk/src/share/classes/java/util/IdentityHashMap.java#L149)

###### Update

I also found that `ThreadLocal.ThreadLocalMap` also uses 2/3 as the load factor, It also uses linear probing to resolve conflicts.

```java
/**
 * Set the resize threshold to maintain at worst a 2/3 load factor.
 */
private void setThreshold(int len) {
    threshold = len * 2 / 3;
}
```

From [jdk/ThreadLocal.java at jdk8-b120 · openjdk/jdk · GitHub](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/jdk8-b120/jdk/src/share/classes/java/lang/ThreadLocal.java#L342)

Comment: Maybe because it uses linear probing, which is [more sensitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_probing#:~:text=its%20performance%20degrades%20more%20quickly%20at%20high%20load%20factors) to high load factors.

Comment: It doesn't use 2/3 as a load factor.  The comment in the code just explains why 32 is a good initial capacity.  It needs to be a power of 2, and it needs to be a bit more than 20.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem 21/32 = 0.65625, 21 ≈ 32 * 2/3. In the `init` method, the initCapacity is multiplied by 2, that is, table.length = 64 by default. In the `put` method, if `(s + (s << 1)> len && resize(len))`, the current `size + 1` multiplied by 3 to determine whether to resize, that is, use 2/3 as the load factor.

Comment: real programmers don't use floating-point?  ;-)

Comment: Why do you think, 0.75 (=3/4) would be a better load factor than 2/3?

Comment: @shmosel it always baffled me why they decided to use this load factor approach instead of just counting the actual number of collisions. In the end, both approaches use an int field but the load factor approach can cause entirely obsolete rehashing operations.

Comment: @Holger I didn’t think which one was better, but wanted to know how these two values were derived.

Comment: Well, we don’t know whether the author(s) of `IdentityHashMap` ever considered using the same load factor as `HashMap`. If they did, shmosel’s conjecture is the most plausible.

Comment: My earlier link compares linear probing to other open addressing strategies. A more key point is that open addressing in general has to be [stricter about load factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_addressing#:~:text=A%20critical%20influence%20on%20performance%20of%20an%20open%20addressing%20hash%20table%20is%20the%20load%20factor), as opposed to chaining, which can theoretically grow infinitely on a single hash bucket.